# Random Selenium Error (element click intercepted: other element would receive the click)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get data from the following page:
https://www.robeco.com/ch/en/funds/prof-ch-en-11/robeco-qi-emerging-conservative-equities-f-eur-lu0940007007.html

I use the following script:

```
url="https://www.robeco.com/ch/en/funds/prof-ch-en-11/robeco-qi-emerging-conservative-equities-f-eur-lu0940007007.html"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

xpath1='/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/button'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath1).click()

time.sleep(2)

xpath2='/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div/ul/li'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath2).click()
```

The first click accepts the general conditions disclaimer. The second click accepts the cookie disclaimer.
I have issues with the second click, as I sometimes get the following error. The behaviour looks random: sometimes the script works, other times the error occurs.

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <li class="btn" id="sdgdpr_modal_buttons-agree">...</li> is not clickable at point (790, 521). Other element would receive the click: <p>...</p>
  (Session info: chrome)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00F1DF13+2219795]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EB2841+1779777]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DC423D+803389]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DF99D4+1022420]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DF78C4+1013956]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DF54AB+1004715]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DF4117+999703]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DE9B76+957302]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E0E7FC+1107964]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DE94B4+955572]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E0EA14+1108500]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E1F192+1175954]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E0E616+1107478]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DE7F89+950153]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DE8F56+954198]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01212CB2+3040210]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01202BB4+2974420]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00FB6A0A+565546]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00FB5680+560544]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EB9A5C+1808988]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EBE3A8+1827752]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EBE495+1827989]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EC80A4+1867940]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75EFFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77C17B5E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77C17B2E+238]
```

What could I do? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1. You need to learn how to create correct locators.  Absolute XPath are extremely fragile and not reliable.
2. You should use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions`, not hardcoded pauses.
3. On the second cookies banner you should click the parent `ul` element, not a child `li` element.

The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://www.robeco.com/ch/en/funds/prof-ch-en-11/robeco-qi-emerging-conservative-equities-f-eur-lu0940007007.html"

driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn-turquoise"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'sdgdpr_modal_buttons'))).click()
```